# Marketo - Invalid Content Type

Tags: marketo

I'm trying to use the insert lead api and I'm getting getting error 612 - "Invalid Content Type"

I know there are 2 different threads, as well as the explanation in the documentation that the request header needs to state "Content-Type: application/json"

I've tried both curl (as per the example in the documentation - which is wrong, btw) as well as java. Both clearly have "Content-Type" "application/json"

Any suggestions? Am I missing something? Any thoughts on how I might troubleshoot?

Any help would be really, really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do think it's related to Content-Type. Here is an example with Postman (chrome plug-in). I would check whether your call works as expected using Postman, then try to incorporate it into your code (Java or cURL).

[image: postman Content-Type]

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I was able to get it working with cURL. Man - those MKTO REST API's seem finicky.